# Need to rearrange JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need to rearrange the my JSON array in following manner. In the output, I need `id` as key and object itself as it's value.

Input:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "sub": [
            {
                "id": "1-1",
                "sub": [
                    {
                        "id": "1-1-1",
                        "sub": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "1-2",
                "sub": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "sub": []
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "sub": [
            {
                "id": "3-1",
                "sub": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Output:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "sub": {
            "1-1": {
                "id": "1-1",
                "sub": {
                    "1-1-1": {
                        "id": "1-1-1",
                        "sub": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "1-2": {
                "id": "1-2",
                "sub": []
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "sub": []
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "sub": {
            "3-1": {
                "id": "3-1",
                "sub": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying it with recursion, but it is creating cyclic object.

```
function rearrange(obj){
  obj[obj.id] = obj;
  for(var j = 0; j < obj.sub.length; j++){
    obj.sub[j][obj.sub[j].id] = obj.sub[j];
    if(obj.sub[j].sub.length > 0){
      rearrange(obj.sub[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

// call

```
rearrange(myobj);
```

Comment: at first sight, I would recommend creating a new plain object and just iterating over your JSON and create the structure you want in the new object instead of trying to "update" the input object. you don't really have a breaking statement in your recursive function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array `map` function. The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var array = [{
    "id": "1",
    "sub": [{
        "id": "1-1",
        "sub": [{
            "id": "1-1-1",
            "sub": []
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "1-2",
        "sub": []
    }]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "sub": []
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "sub": [{
        "id": "3-1",
        "sub": []
    }]
}];

function doMap(arr) {
    var output = arr.map(function(d) {
        var ob = {};
        if (d.sub)
            d.sub = doMap(d.sub);
        ob[d.id] = d;
        return ob;
    });
    return output;
};

alert(JSON.stringify(doMap(array)));
```

The output obtained

```
[{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "sub": [{
            "1-1": {
                "id": "1-1",
                "sub": [{
                    "1-1-1": {
                        "id": "1-1-1",
                        "sub": []
                    }
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "1-2": {
                "id": "1-2",
                "sub": []
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "sub": []
    }
}, {
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "sub": [{
            "3-1": {
                "id": "3-1",
                "sub": []
            }
        }]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Hi Gilsha, thanks for the answer. At second level, it is creating object with key as `undefined`. I haven't used `map` before, so I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Hello benjamin. I could not reproduce the issue you mentioned. I have added a formatted output to the answer. Isn't it the expected output? I could not find any object with key as undefined in that.